# import text file in r keep correct variables positions

Tags: r, text, import

I have a txt file and the data looks like the following.I want to import it to R.

```
Sequences (   1:   2) %id:    8   Score:      10   Len:       1
Sequences (   1:  10) %id:   25   Score:      30   Len:       3
Sequences (  61: 624) %id:   75   Score:      90   Len:      12
Sequences (  61: 625) %id:   33   Score:      40   Len:      12
Sequences ( 860: 939) %id:   41   Score:      50   Len:       7
Sequences ( 860: 940) %id:   16   Score:      20   Len:       6
Sequences (1248:1395) %id:    8   Score:      10   Len:       1
Sequences (1248:1396) %id:   33   Score:      40   Len:       8
```

When I use read.table

```
df<-read.table("seq_TEXT INPUT_text.txt",sep = " ", header = F, fill = TRUE)
```

But it does not work, it becomes the following..[image]

I hope the result looks like

```
       V1 V2 V3 V4  V5  V6  V7 V8  V9     V10 V11   V12   V13 V14   V15
Sequences (   1  :   2  )  %id :    8   Score :      10   Len :       1
Sequences (   1  :  10  )  %id :   25   Score :      30   Len :       3
Sequences (  61  : 624  )  %id :   75   Score :      90   Len :      12
Sequences (  61  : 625  )  %id :   33   Score :      40   Len :      12
Sequences ( 860  : 939  )  %id :   41   Score :      50   Len :       7
Sequences ( 860  : 940  )  %id :   16   Score :      20   Len :       6
Sequences (1248  :1395  )  %id :    8   Score :      10   Len :       1
Sequences (1248  :1396  )  %id :   33   Score :      40   Len :       8
```

How can we do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try `sep="\t"`? I think you will need to use some `?regex` code here.

Comment: `read.table` is best for delimited data. It looks like you have more of a fixed-width format. Look at `read.fwf` instead.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you. I finally try the read_fwf, because it is much much faster.( I have 1 million rows.) Thanks for the information. I am such as rookie. I even do not know how to find this code at beginning. Thank you again.